# Python code to read first 14 characters, uniquefy based on them, and parse duplicates

Tags: string, parsing, python-3.x, sequences, fasta

I have a list of more than 10k os string that look like different versions of this (HN5ML6A02FL4UI_3 [14 numbers or letters_1-6]), where some are duplicates except for the _1 to _6.

I am trying to find a way to list these and remove the duplicate 14 character (that comes before the _1-_6).

Example of part of the list:

`HN5ML6A02FL4UI_3`

`HN5ML6A02FL4UI_1`

`HN5ML6A01BDVDN_6`

`HN5ML6A01BDVDN_1`

`HN5ML6A02GVTSV_3`

`HN5ML6A01CUDA2_1`

`HN5ML6A01CUDA2_5`

`HN5ML6A02JPGQ9_5`

`HN5ML6A02JI8VU_1`

`HN5ML6A01AJOJU_5`

I have tried versions of scripts using Reg Expressions: `var n = /\d+/.exec(info)[0];` into the following that were posted into my previous question. and

I also used a modified version of the code from : [How can I strip the first 14 characters in an list element using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174528/how-can-i-strip-the-first-14-characters-in-an-list-element-using-python)

More recently I used this script and I am still not getting the correct output.

```
import os, re

def trunclist('rhodopsins_play', 'hope4'):
    with open('rhodopsins_play','r') as f:
        newlist=[]
        trunclist=[]
        for line in f:
            if line.strip().split('_')[0] not in trunclist:
                newlist.append(line)
                trunclist.append(line.split('_')[0])
    print newlist, trunclist

    # write newlist to file, with carriage returns
    with open('hope4','w') as out:
        for line in newlist:
            out.write(line)
```

My *inputfile.txt* contains more than 10k of data which looks like the list above, where the important part are the characters are in front of the '_' (underscore), then outputting a file of the uniquified `ABCD12356_1`.

Can someone help?

Thank you for your help

Comment: for the example i would want an output file

HN5ML6A02FL4UI_3

HN5ML6A01BDVDN_6

HN5ML6A02GVTSV_3

HN5ML6A01CUDA2_1

HN5ML6A02JPGQ9_5

HN5ML6A02JI8VU_1

HN5ML6A01AJOJU_5

Answer (score 0):

Import python and run this script that is similar to the above.  It is slitting at the '_'  This worked on the file

```
def trunclist(inputfile, outputfile):
with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
    newlist=[]
    trunclist=[]
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().split('_')[0] not in trunclist:
            newlist.append(line)
            trunclist.append(line.split('_')[0])
print newlist, trunclist

# write newlist to file, with carriage returns
with open(outputfile,'w') as out:
    for line in newlist:
        out.write(line)
```